# Bootstrap template in symfony

Tags: javascript, php, css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I bought bootstrap template and try to implement it to my symfony project, but it does not works.
I included css and js like this:

```
<link href="{{ asset('/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

What i did wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the output in your HTML to see what URL that is referencing and if it is correct?

Comment: yes, I checked it, its okay

Comment: What is wrong then? Clicking on the link shows the CS/JS in your browser? In that case it has worked...

Comment: https://ibb.co/ccqn0Q this is the problem, on right side its in symfony

Comment: I'm afraid that screenshot means nothing to me, it could be anything of 100 problems. Do you have a link to that page?

Comment: Your problem description is rather brief.. Perhaps try checking the Network tab in your browsers developer tools and confirm that the stylesheet is actually downloaded (status 200), then be sure that you applied the appropriate classes to your elements.

Comment: No, I dont have link to that page, its only local now, when I click on link shows the CSS, it show me css file. Does symfony needs to configure something?

Comment: With the link that you provided you include only css not js. Also make sure you include all the template files as well. And try to clear the cache with `bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` or `--env=dev` depending on your enviroment.

Answer (score 1):

Put your bootstrap assets folders (css, js, images...) in your web folder.
Next use this code:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

in your twig template.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your website, locally or not, and press CTRL-i. Here, browse the DOM of your page and look if the stylesheet path is valid or not. This will be the first step to find where the issue is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

It's important in Symfony to use blocks and one folder assets inside of folder web.

Example:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
        <link href="{{ asset('assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap.cosmo.min.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/styles.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endblock %}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in XAMPP, swapped to VertigoServ and it works now.